# Highest rate achievable by current DSP and A/D chips?

Tags: adaptive-filters, performance

I'm trying to determine whether an application I have in mind is feasible with currently available DSP technology (DSP chips and ADCs).

I want to eliminate an interfering signal using an LMS adaptive filter.  I have access to the source of the interference.

The bandwidth of the interfering signal is in the order of 1MHz  (maybe a little less, but just as a conservative assumption, let's say 1MHz).  The bandwidth of the signal I want to measure can be higher; possibly in the order of 10MHz or 20MHz.

**EDIT:** I estimate that the application will require sampling at no less than 12-bit resolution.

Does the above sound feasible?  Could you suggest some DSP chips that you'd estimate could potentially handle the above workload?

If it sounds like it's **not** feasible, can you give an estimate of what you think would be the highest bandwidth that current DSP chips could handle?

You may assume that the DSP chip will be doing exclusively this;  or maybe just some "lightweight" additional work.

Thanks!

Comment: 20 MHz signal bandwidth is pretty LMS processible in real-time (assuming 8 bit samples). You might consider using external ADC chips though. But I believe, even on chip ADC's can be fast enough to handle this. You know **where** to look for those chips right?

Comment: @Fat32: Huh --- I thought I had mentioned in the original message that I estimate I may need to sample at no less than 12-bit resolution  (I will edit it to clarify).  When you say "where to look for those chips", are you talking about the ADCs?  Analog Devices seems to offer a good selection of them  (that's even excluding the LT models they list now).  If you were referring to DSP chips fast enough for this, with suitable on-chip ADCs, well, not necessarily --- any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Hmm ok. 12 bits may be even 16 bits. You shall look for Gigasamplers for digital oscilloscopes... They are not 16 bits though. One thing further, you can combine a number of (say N) slower ADC's into a circular multirate structure to achieve N times faster sampling, with some good clock syncronisation too,  if a single chip does not satisfy your goals. Yes I mean TI, ST, ADI, NI, NXP kind of vendors' pages... Sorry I dont have a catalog now to select or offer.

Comment: you could probably use an FPGA for that. Though FPGA design has a steep learning curve, it is sometimes the only solution.

Comment: @Ben:  Yes, I figured FPGA might be a valid solution;  I do have some basic familiarity with it;  however, I think I'll have a hard time selling the idea to my supervisor  (who is adamantly opposed to using FPGA, claiming that it gets messy and horribly dependent on vendors and quirky tools)

Comment: 1 - Does your considered DSP support the ADC interface(s) ?
2 - Is your boss open to a hybrid architecture with a DSP and an FPGA?

Comment: @Ben: your point 1 is something I know I will have to consider when looking for the specific DSProcessor and the specific ADC (or DSP with on-chip ADCs, if available at this level of computing power).  As for item 2 --- he is generally opposed to including FPGA, because developing with it becomes a big problem.  I don't think he would oppose to it if we could objectively see that FPGA represents a much better solution to the given problem (which may not be the case in this particular instance)

Comment: @Cal-linux I really don't see why anyone would need anything more beefy than a modern PC for this a priory. Don't start with adding specialized hardware to a problem prior to proving it can't be easily solved on standard CPUs.

Comment: @MarcusMüller:  Oh no --- wait, this is for an *embedded* device;  it's not software that we're doing;  the project as a whole will end up in a "gadget/device" that may end up being the size of a hard disk (ballpark).  So no, PC is not an option --- in your answer, I figured you meant that if a PC can do it, then a mid- or high-end DSP chip can do it even more easily  (is that not the case?)

Comment: not "more easily"! "with large development effort", yes. I'd really look into x86 boards first - note that I said "standard CPU", and you can find Intel core i7s in much smaller things than laptops.

Comment: DSPs aren't generally "faster" than CPUs; on the contrary, their clock rate is typically significantly lower. However, they are geared towards very specific operations, which they implement very fast. Whether your specific problem even maps to the abilities of just any DSP isn't a given; plus you'd still need some application processor, typically, with which you control your overall system. Whatever you'd do, you'd *always* first write a proof-of-concept on a PC, if that's possible, especially to have something to analyze; without knowing what the computationally hard things are, how would …

Comment: … you know what even *needs* acceleration through dedicated DSP hardware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty benign requirement. The Open Source software defined radio community does significantly more than 100 MS/s complex samples in software running on stock PC hardware. The samples come from stock SDR hardware.

However, you wouldn't be doing a 100s of taps long channel estimator / LMS filter at that rate.

It's impossible to estimate the computational complexity of your problem without at least knowing what kind of interferer you want to cancel. However, 10 MS/s really doesn't sound dramatic at all.

Comment: Given the discussion above, I have (at least for the time being) unmarked this as the answer --- though I agree with implementing a proof-of-concept/prototype version on a desktop PC, I still think that dedicated DSP hardware may end up being the better-suited alternative.  So, that brings me back to the original question, which given the comments above, I'm now unsure whether the above answers.

Comment: The title question is impossible to answer: "Highest achievable rate" means you'd have to first specify what you need in processing, **exactly**. You also don't care about the highest rate at all – you need to know what hardware can solve your problem. Be sure to ask the questions you want an answer to!

Comment: also, honestly, there's zero proof that one or the other (standard CPU vs dedicated DSP hardware) is better suited for your problem. So, not quite sure where you get your conviction that dedicated DSP will be better suited – remember, "better suited" also means you'll have to be able to use it.

Comment: (again, 10 or 20 MS/s and a simple adaptive filter really is far below the threshold where I'd even consider using something as complex as a DSP board, leave alone developing one on my own or doing a complex FPGA design. Just run it on a CPU, you'll probably be fine. These rates aren't "high".)

Comment: "*Be sure to ask the questions you want an answer to*" --- fair enough;  however, the question very explicitly refers to "DSP chips";  your answer, I understood it as "if the SDR people do 100s of MHz with stock PC hardware, you can achieve it with DSP chips", and it wasn't clear that you were suggesting that I should consider using desktop PC processors *instead* of DSP chips.  In that sense is that I see my question still unanswered.  If you could confirm that my interpretation here is correct, and that the task looks comfortable for DSP chips, then I would consider it answered.

Comment: No, you shouldn't do that. I'll repeat what I said above: it's no given that any specific DSP chip can do your specific workload at all. DSPs are specialized chips. At any rate, if you don't have experience, then learning and using a specialized platform is not "comfortable", by any means.

Comment: I guess the best solution will be for me to post a separate question, narrowing down what I'm asking.  In a nutshell, as much as in your answer you suggest that my problem seems manageable with PC hardware, and you stated that as an estimate, without knowing specific requirements;  well, I'd like to get an estimate like that for DSP chips.  You did emphasize that the requirement does not look intimidating, but I wonder if that statement is 100% specific to solving the problem on PC hardware.

Comment: "For DSP chips": there's literally hundreds out there, and you'll have to really pick your platform of interest, and describe in very much detail what you need accelerated. Take my word, this will be much easier for you to ask once you've worked on an implementation yourself. I can't tell you how intimidating the problem looks on "DSP Chips" because that is not a single homogenous mass, at all. "PC style CPU" at least *tries* to roughly nail down an order of magnitudes on *any* FLOP/s you want to do. The same doesn't work for DSPs. Again, these are special-purpose devices. For some problems,

Comment: they can be blazingly fast, for others, they simply are slower than a raspberry pi. Which problems they are optimized for depends on the individual chip.